# Is there ways to know which outlook record is created in salesforce from outlook

Tags: integration, salesforce-for-outlook, connect-for-outlook

Is there ways to know which outlook record is created in salesforce contact from outlook. I successfully sync outlook contact into salesforce contact. But i need to know how can i differentiate normal salesforce record with outlook record??? how can i do it???

Answer (score 0):

Create a new list view with last modify date field in Salesforce and that will give you a list of Contacts name with the late modify date, there you can easily differentiate old Salesforce record with new contact that you have just sync via Salesfoce for Outlook.

Best way to differentiate would be access Sync log (Win+R - > Run - > %appdata -> salesforce.com - > salesforce for outlook - sync log) for the random date.